# in C# windows apps, the Transparency in my textbox made it as if it wasn't there

Tags: c#, transparency, richtextbox

hey guys I used this code to enable Transparency to my form:

```
private void TypingFreak_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
   this.TransparencyKey = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Control);
   this.Update();
}
```

BUT, it became as if wasn't there, so if I'm running it on my desktop, I could see the icons and react with them (I can't write to the textbox)

in my form, I have 2 rich textBoxes that I want them to be transparent to the backcolor of my form background .. 
any idea how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

TransparencyKey makes the form behave as if it wasn't there in places with that colour. In your case it's the background colour of all content controls (such as TextBox, ListBox, etc.) and thus almost the whole form is invisible. Or probably if your form has a different color then you get holes in places where you put such a control.

You would need to make the control itself transparent by setting a transparent background colour, but not all controls support this. In fact, RichTextBox (and TextBox) does not:

[image]

leads to

[image]

Comment: can i make a textbox control transparent in a way or another ?

Comment: TextBox doesn't support it either. From what I see Label is one of the few that does. You could probably make a subclassed TextBox control that tries figuring out where on the form it is and uses a suitable rectangular snippet of the forms background image as its own background image or something along that lines. Depending on what you exactly want to do. Or move to WPF.